# Load Android Native library with Java reflection

Tags: java, android, reflection, java-native-interface, java-native-library

I'm trying to load an Android native library with Java reflection, but at runtime the library is not found. Normally i load a native library with:

```
System.loadLibrary("mylib");
```

and everything works as expected. Now i try to call the `loadLibrary` method with reflection, like this:

```
Class<?> system = Class.forName("java.lang.System");
Method loadLibrary = system.getDeclaredMethod("loadLibrary", String.class);
loadLibrary.invoke(null, "mylib");
```

but at runtime i get:

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Library mylib not found; tried [/system/lib64/libmylib.so, /vendor/lib64/libmylib.so]
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1001)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1530)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
```

It seems like with reflection `loadLibrary` look for the library in the wrong path. These `/system/lib64:/vendor/lib64` are the paths of `java.library.path` property, but it does not look inside the apk. Of course the library is present in the final apk, and it's in the right place, for the right ABI.

**NOTE**

I can't use

```
System.load("absolute-path-to-lib/mylib.so");
```

because from where i'm calling this i don't have the path available, i don't have any `Context` or `Application` available yet to retrive the path.

Do you have any idea how to force `loadLibrary` to search in the current apk ? Thank you!

Comment: From where are you trying to do this? AFAIK it is the ClassLoader associated with the calling class that is responsible for finding the library.

Comment: I tried in the static initializer of a random Class but also in a simple Android instrumentedTest. In both cases i get the same output, no matter where i call this i always get the `UnsatisfiedLinkError`.

Comment: What actual problem are you trying to solve? Why can’t you just stay with `System.loadLibrary("mylib");` which you said to work as expected?

Comment: I want to hide as much as possible the loading of the native library. It's easy to find `System.loadLibrary` in the bytecode, but with reflection, the class and method became string which i can then encrypt with DexGuard or similar.